# How can i share an image with a different url using addThis plugin

Tags: php, addthis

I am using addThis social plugin in my site.I need to share a particular image from my page and it should link to some other url. Is it possible. please help me.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Google URL shortner` to create a SAME but different url. Below is the link

http://goo.gl/

Example -

```
1) Actual URL of an image - http://hearstcommerce.ca/customcontent/members/premium/sample.jpg
2) Different URL but same image - http://goo.gl/rZLMma
```

The 2nd URL seems to be different but after clicking it, it redirects you to the same URL.

Comment: When i share a url, facebook picks an image from the url given.I need to change this default image